# Word Automation Services in Sharepoint 2010 to replace content in a Word Document

Tags: 2010, word-automation

I have a scenario in which I have to replace few contents in a word document based on the library / list input form of sharepoint 2010.

Example :

I have 2 Placeholders : [Title] and [SubTitle]

Now, if the end user, using sharepoint's default new form enters the value of Title and SubTitle as "New" and "NewTest" respectively then this should get replaced in the word document on the submission of the new form.

how to accomplish this using server side code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without writing single line of code if you want to do in document library(Not in list).

You can create one word template for document library and add field place holder to that file. SharePoint will update its value automatically once you update it in new/edit form.

Visit [this](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/07/sharepoint-connecting-metadata-in-office-documents-to-sharepoint-library-columns/) to know how to configure it.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: what I want is that I already have a template created say for HR Policy System of a company , In that when the user fills the forms the content place holder should get replaces with the inputs. In this I dont want to display the document template to the user. And after successful completion of the replacement the template should be converted in pdf and there should be a separate file created. i.e. if the template is Policy1 then the edited document should be a new document with name as Policy_Leaves.

Comment: I want to achieve this using server side coding, with event receivers and using open xml

Comment: And can you tell me how to apply information rights management for a word document.

Comment: user will add information in list or library?

Comment: The documents will get saved in a library.

Comment: I mean where user will fill metadata? is it list or library?

Comment: Library,

the case is I will be having multiple formats of policies i.e Leave, Retention, Holidays etc. and will be having different fields to get replaced in the respective templates

Comment: Ok.. that means it have different content type added on library according to policies. right?

Comment: the solution you mentioned in the answer will work in all versions of sharepoint and microsoft office ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30198/discussion-between-vishwas-goswami-and-kalpesh-vaghela).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SharePoint specific question and it might get moved to another board.
Follow the following steps and make changes where needed.

1. Install Open XML SDK 2.5 on server. More info: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278315.aspx)
2. Add required references. More on this: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
3. Open the document from the library:

   `byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("PATH_TO_DOCUMENT_IN_LIBRARY");
   MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
   mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
   WordprocessingDocument _wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true);
   string _w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
   MainDocumentPart part = _wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
   NameTable nt = new NameTable();
   XmlNamespaceManager _nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
   XmlNamespaceManager _nsManager.AddNamespace("w", _w);
   XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
   XmlDocument _xmlDoc.Load(part.GetStream());`
4. Insert text into a bookmark:

   `public void InsertTextIntoBookmark(string bookmarkName, string text)
   {
       if ((text != String.Empty) && (text != null))
       {
           //find it
           XmlElement bookmarkStartNode = (XmlElement)_xmlDoc.
            DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//w:bookmarkStart[@w:name='" + bookmarkName + "']", this._nsManager);
           XmlNodeList followingNodesList = bookmarkStartNode.
           SelectNodes(".//following::w:t | .//following::w:bookmarkEnd[@w:name='" + bookmarkName + "']", this._nsManager);
           foreach (XmlElement el in followingNodesList)
           {
               var res = from bm in this._wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.BookmarkStart>()
                         where bm.Name == bookmarkName
                         select bm;
               var bk = res.SingleOrDefault();
               if (bk != null)
               {
                   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run bookmarkText =
               bk.NextSibling<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run>();
                   if (bookmarkText != null)
                   {
   bookmarkText.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>().Text = text;
                       el.InnerText = text;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       var parent = bk.Parent; // bookmark's parent element
                       DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run run =
                           new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(
                               new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties());
                       DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text txt =
                           new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(text);
                       run.Append(txt);
                       // insert after bookmark parent
                       parent.Append(run);
                   }
                   bk.Remove();
               }
           }
           //flush to doc
    _xmlDoc.Save(_wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
       }
   }`

Hope this helps.

P.S. Someone please help me to format the code :)